# Insulation in basement with plaster walls

Tags: concrete, insulation, basement, plaster

I’m looking to finish my basement. I have a 1940’s cape cod with a poured concrete basement. The basement walls have a fairly thick layer of plaster to them, very rough looking. It’s   and in good shape. No water issues.  I want to treat the plaster like it’s part of the concrete walls and do glue with EPS board. On top of that I’d build my frame/bays for my walls. Roxul batts with no vapor barrier and then dry wall.

Alternatively, I thought I could just frame out the basement on top of the plaster, use no insulation, and then do whatever finish I wanted (drywall, paneling, etc). I don’t get any added insulation but I also won’t break the plaster and I’d get the look I wanted.

Any help or input is appreciated!

Comment: You have listed several alternatives but it isn't clear what your objectives and priorities are.  What input are you looking for?

Comment: Can I safely frame walls and/or insulate over plaster on concrete in a basement? Or will I end up with mold/a mess?